# Removing rows based on content of a JSON cell

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a table containing a column of JSON. The data inside the JSON column is organized as follows:

```
[{"name":"Apple","short_name":"A"},{"name":"Banana","short_name":"B"}]
```

Most rows only have one name/short name, but some (like the example above) have more than one. What I need to do is to remove any rows from my select that have Kiwi in their JSON cell.

I tried using `WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(persons.fruits, '"Kiwi"', '$')`, and also tried `JSON_ARRAY_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(persons.fruits, '$'), 'Kiwi')`
and got the error that the function was not found for both functions. I may be misusing the functions, this is my first time trying to use them. What should I do?

Comment: big query has not such function https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_query

Comment: Maybe something like `WHERE 'Kiwi' IN UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(person.fruits, '$.name'))`

Answer (score 0):

You have to unnest the array and search for values inside the JSONs. There are several approaches but they all involve querying for the different values that are available in each row's array.

Using your provided structure as an example, here's a query that will filter out rows where the value 'Kiwi' exists as a name in one of the array records:

```
WITH base_data AS (
  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Apple","short_name":"A"},{"name":"Banana","short_name":"B"}]') as fruits_array
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Kiwi","short_name":"K"},{"name":"Banana","short_name":"B"}]') as fruits_array

  UNION ALL

  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Apple","short_name":"A"},{"name":"Kiwi","short_name":"K"}]') as fruits_array
)

select *
from base_data
where 'Kiwi' not in (SELECT JSON_VALUE(fruit_json.name) FROM UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(fruits_array)) fruit_json)
```

This query will work assuming your values are strictly JSON.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgZo4.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWppq.png)

The way this works:

- For each row, we calculate in a subquery the list of available values in each record's "name" key
- Using our where statement, we then filter out any row where the value 'Kiwi' exists in that list of available values, resulting in keeping only rows that don't have the value 'Kiwi'

Another possible solution is treating the JSON as a pure string and looking for the actual string of 'Kiwi' - but this method is not exactly bullet-proof and I would not suggest relying on it heavily:

```
WITH base_data AS (
  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Apple","short_name":"A"},{"name":"Banana","short_name":"B"}]') as fruits_array
  
  UNION ALL

  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Kiwi","short_name":"K"},{"name":"Banana","short_name":"B"}]') as fruits_array

  UNION ALL

  SELECT PARSE_JSON('[{"name":"Apple","short_name":"A"},{"name":"Kiwi","short_name":"K"}]') as fruits_array
)

select *
from base_data
where TO_JSON_STRING(fruits_array) NOT LIKE '%Kiwi%'
```